# Full Calendar plus more event displaying

Tags: javascript, asp.net, events, calendar

I trying to implementing scheduler in web application.

I am using full calendar for scheduler ,I am showing all scheduled event on days and I have set eventLimit on day as  4.
Now I have question how can i show plus more event on other day have not any events.

Eg:

1. Event Start Date 13 Jan 2017  and EndDate 21 Jan 2017.
2. Event Start Date 16 Jan 2017 :Have 4 events. End date :18 Jan 2017.
    [Note :2nd displaying 4 events with title on 16 Jan to 18 Jan]

   Now 1st event start 13 Jan 2017  to 21 Jan 2017 When event goes 16 Jan 2017 then event limit do automatically plus more 1 .same continue on 17 Jan to 21 Jan 2017.

Now Question is 19 ,20 ,21 Jan 2017 have not any events then event should be displayed with title. but this kind of not happens it displaying plus more 1 on 19 ,20 ,21 Jan 2017.]

How can we show plus more event with title on the day have any events ?

thanks in Advance.